Issue with Preserving Custom Range Values for Shape Keys in Blender
I’ve encountered a challenge while working with shape keys in Blender.
I’m currently creating facial expressions using shape keys. I started with a shape key named ‘Mouth_Smile_L’ to create a smiling expression on the left side of the face. My intention was to use ‘New Shape from Mix’ and then apply ‘Mirror Shape Key (Topology)’ to create a mirrored shape key on the right side.
Here’s where I’m facing an issue:
I set the Range Min and Max for ‘Mouth_Smile_L’ to -1.5 and 1.5, respectively. However, when I use ‘New Shape from Mix’, the new shape key reverts to the default Range Min and Max values. This means that even though I set the Range Max of ‘Mouth_Smile_L’ to 1.5, when mirrored, the ‘Mouth_Smile_R’ has a Max value of 1.0 by default. If I manually adjust ‘Mouth_Smile_R’ to have a Max value of 1.5, it results in an exaggerated transformation, which is not what I want.

I would like to achieve the same transformation value for both ‘Mouth_Smile_L’ and ‘Mouth_Smile_R’ with a Max of 1.5. How can I ensure that the mirrored shape key retains the same Max value as the original?
